# how to each_cons in batches with active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

The following throws a `LocalJumpError`

```
records.find_each.each_cons(3)
```

Is there a built-in way to use each_cons in memory-friendly batches?

---

*Edit:*

Ideally the overlap would work across the batch limit. `each_cons` interates over overlapping groups, so records with ids (0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4) etc.

If the batch size is 1000 (which I think it is for Rails), it would be less than optimal to have the overlap limited within the batch group. For example the records with indexes (997, 998, 999) then next iteration to (1000, 1001, 1002) is undesirable.

Comment: @beck03076 the model represents changes, so retroactively deleting redundant records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, like this:

```
User.all.find_in_batches do |group|
  group.each_cons(3) { |users| puts users.map(&:name) }
end
```

Comment: would that work across groups? For instance if the batch size is 1000, would I get a group of (999, 1000, 1001)?

Comment: huh, what? i don't understand your question.

Comment: i really have no clue what you want to do here, but you could achive that by calling find_in_batches with a batch-size that is modulo 0 from your each_cons size

Answer (score 1):

Here's a custom method to accomplish it:

```
def batched_each_cons(batch_size:, each_cons:, model:)
  end_of_previous = []
  model.find_in_batches(batch_size: batch_size) do |batch|
    rebuilt_batch = end_of_previous + batch
    end_of_previous = batch[(-(each_cons-1))..-1]
    rebuilt_batch.each_cons(each_cons) do |cons|
      yield cons
    end
  end
end

batched_each_cons(batch_size: 5, each_cons: 3, model: User) do | users |
  # puts users.map(&:name)
  puts users.map(&:id).inspect
end
```

This gives:

```
 User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 5]]
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 4]
[3, 4, 5]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" > $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 5]]
[4, 5, 6]
[5, 6, 7]
[6, 7, 8]
[7, 8, 9]
[8, 9, 10]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" > $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 10], ["LIMIT", 5]]
[9, 10, 11]
[10, 11, 12]
[11, 12, 13]
[12, 13, 14]
[13, 14, 15]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" > $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 5]]
[14, 15, 16]
[15, 16, 17]
[16, 17, 18]
[17, 18, 19]
[18, 19, 20]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" > $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 20], ["LIMIT", 5]]
```

(This is in my local console, normally you would not see 'User Load...', that is there to show the batching is working)